# Java Game Images

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am making a game in Java and I have a class which loads images like so

```
class ImageLoader {
     public static ImageIcon image_1 = new ImageIcon(this.class.getResource(file_name_of_image);
     public static ImageIcon image_2 = new ImageIcon(this.class.getResource(file_name_of_image);
     public static ImageIcon image_3 = new ImageIcon(this.class.getResource(file_name_of_image);
     public static ImageIcon image_4 = new ImageIcon(this.class.getResource(file_name_of_image);

    public Image getImage1() {
        return image_1.getImage();
    }
}
```

I call them like

```
// paint method
g.draw(ImageLoader.getImage1()...);
```

or

```
setIcon(ImageLoader.image_1);
```

My problem is that when my program runs, there is a high CPU usage, which I assume is from having to load this images on every repaint and also I should mention, the images may not be the same size as their components so some scaling needs to be done.

Should I be using a `BufferedImage` for this? Or may someone explain to me what I may be doing wrong, or what the problem is?

Comment: Please post you `paint()` code. It is likely that code has some inefficiencies in it.

Comment: you can use jvisualvm to profile your application, that should tell you what is using the cpu.

Answer (score 4):

I think your high CPU must be coming from somewhere else.  Once these static variables are loaded, they are not loaded a second time, regardless of repaint.  There could be high cpu at the start of your program while it loads them once, but I don't see any reason it would load them a second time.

Comment: Aha, I notice the load go up, but it doesn't come back down which is why i suspected it to be something with the graphics, since the game isn't that big and the graphics are the most intensive part. Thank you, I will look into it

Comment: The time between paint cycles could be to short